# MySQL select - If a column value is redundant, only show the newest by timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
timesent            |nr | value 
2018-10-31 05:23:06 | 4 | Value 3
2018-10-31 05:20:19 | 4 | Value 2
2018-10-31 05:19:35 | 4 | Value 1
2018-10-31 04:55:56 | 3 | Value 2
2018-10-31 03:05:15 | 3 | Value 1
2018-10-31 01:31:49 | 2 | Value 1
2018-10-30 04:11:16 | 1 | Value 1
```

At the moment, my select looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM values WHERE ORDER BY timesent DESC
```

I want to do an sql-select statement which gives me back only the most recent value of each "nr".

My skills are not good enough to translate that into a sql-statement. I don´t even know what I should google for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Values` is a [Reserved Keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-V). Consider changing your table name to something else; otherwise you will have to use backticks around it

There are various ways to achieve the result for your problem. One way is to do a "Self-Left-Join" on `nr` (field on which you want to get the maximum `timesent` value row only).

```
SELECT v1.* 
FROM `values` AS v1 
LEFT JOIN `values` AS v2 
  ON v1.nr = v2.nr AND 
     v1.timesent < v2.timesent 
WHERE v2.nr IS NULL
```

---

For [MySQL version >= **8.0.2**](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/), you can use [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). We will determine [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) for each row over a partition of `nr`, with `timesent` in Descending order (Highest `timesent` value will have row number = 1). Then, use this result-set in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and consider only those rows, where row number is equal to 1.

```
SELECT dt.timesent,  
       dt.nr, 
       dt.value 
FROM 
(
  SELECT v.timesent, v.nr, v.value, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.nr 
                            ORDER BY v.timesent DESC) AS row_num  
  FROM `values` AS v 
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.row_num = 1
```

---

Yet, another approach is to get the maximum value of `timesent` for a `nr` group in a Derived Table. Now join this result-set to the main table, so that only the rows corresponding to max value appear:

```
SELECT v.timesent,  
       v.nr, 
       v.value 
FROM 
`values` AS v 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT nr, MAX(timesent) AS max_timesent
  FROM `values` 
  GROUP BY nr 
) AS dt ON dt.nr = v.nr AND 
           dt.max_timesent = v.timesent
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I don´t understand it right now but try to figure it out. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Holy moley - I understand nothing. What do the "v1."´s, "v"´s and "dt."´s in front of the column names?

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer These are Aliases. They make query readable, and unambiguous, when it involved multiple tables/subqueries etc. Do go through this tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Comment: Thank you. I´ll do that. I looked at your profile and you are part of the top 1% mysql answerers. - It shows :) - Your pretty damn good

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer thanks for the kind words. If any explanation needed on these steps; do let me know; I shall update the answer. If this answer has helped you, do consider marking it as accepted answer, and kindly upvote as well. Thanks :)